# Fancyhdr footer with hyperref, the link area is the whole footer, not the desired text

Tags: hyperref, header-footer, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\title{Notes}
\date{2020\\ July}
\author{John Doe}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[R]{\hyperlink{toc}{{\tiny Table of Contents}}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}} %% Add a link target to the TOC itself

\chapter{Pre Flight}
\blindtext
\section{section one}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I would like the text “Table of Contents” to link back to the table of contents, but the link area is currently offset to the area above it, the bit in blue:
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. How are you compiling? Also your document wouldn't give such a shifted text, so you are probably not showing real code.

Comment: Hi, sorry I was using texpad with local typesetting. I have now changed it to pdfLateX and is compiling. When you say ‘real’ code, do you mean what would be on a .tex document if not using a helper such as texpad? Or real in terms that this is not in LaTeX?

Comment: you mean texpad outputted this from your example? Well then something is either wrong with texpad or with your code for it. But I don't use texpad, ask their support.

Comment: How do you typeset your .tex docs? Out of interest?

Comment: I'm on windows, I normally use an editor (winedt) and texlive2020. Sometimes I also compile in other editors like texworks or texstudio, or directly on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, I used to pdfLatex compile in bash, but am finding texpad to be a lot easier. (I only use LaTeX semi-regularly though)

Comment: sure if you want. But texpad is a closed system and only available on mac, so if you have problems with it, it is better to ask their support.

Comment: I’m on the ipad, so my only real options are textpad or a linux-based cloud system such as pythonanywhere